# How can I put the left table outside of the margin just like in the photo?

Tags: formatting, header-footer

[image: Screenshot of a document, depicting the intended result]

I tried with this. It's similar, but it's not outside of the margin.

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c}
 Departamento de Ciencias Básicas \\
     Facultad de Ingeniería\\
      I \, U \,  A\\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\qquad \qquad 
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
  Ingeniería Mecánica Aeronáutica\\
  Ingeniería Electrónica \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{6mm}
\\
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{l}
 \large{E}\small{XAMEN DE} \large{A}\small{NÁLISIS} \large{M}\small{ATEMÁTICO} \large{III} \\
     \large{30/6/2022}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\qquad \qquad \quad \qquad
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|}
         \hline 
         \,\,1& \,\,2 &\,\,3 &\,\,4 & \,\% \\
         \hline
         & & & & \\
         & & & & \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\\\\\\
\large \textbf{Apellido y Nombre:}
\vspace{2pt}
\hrule
```

[image: The output, produced by the above LaTeX code.]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/134641)!

Comment: Please make your code ready to compile, i.e. start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `changepage` package and adjustwidth command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,array}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\begin{document}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{-2cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        Departamento de Ciencias Básicas \\
        Facultad de Ingeniería\\
        I \, U \,  A\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        Ingeniería Mecánica Aeronáutica\\
        Ingeniería Electrónica \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth}
\vspace{6mm}
\mbox{}\\
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \large{E}\small{XAMEN DE} \large{A}\small{NÁLISIS} \large{M}\small{ATEMÁTICO} \large{III} \\
        \large{30/6/2022}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\qquad \qquad \quad \qquad
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|}
        \hline 
        \,\,1& \,\,2 &\,\,3 &\,\,4 & \,\% \\
        \hline
        & & & & \\
        & & & & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\\\\\\
\large \textbf{Apellido y Nombre:}
\vspace{2pt}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Does this work for you?
[image]

Comment: Yes it does, thank you very much, friend.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying Venkatamaran's answer slightly, here's an other way to do it:

- (1) used option `[t]` for `minipage` to align the first two text block "top"
- (2) centering is somewhat duplicate, so I commented out what doesn't hurt
- (3) suggested using `\hspace{}` to move the numerical table to the right
- (4) suggested adding `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` to take care of hyphenation etc. later

[image: top of page]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,array}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}% <<< (4) suggestion; will take care of hyphenation etc.

\begin{document}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{-2cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}% <<< (1) aligning tops
    \centering
%    \begin{tabular}{c}% <<< (2) duplicated centering
        Departamento de Ciencias Básicas \\
        Facultad de Ingeniería\\
        I \, U \,  A\\
%    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}% <<< (1) aligning tops
    \centering
%    \begin{tabular}{c}% <<< (2) duplicated centering
        Ingeniería Mecánica Aeronáutica\\
        Ingeniería Electrónica \\
%    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth}
\vspace{6mm}
\mbox{}\\
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \large{E}\small{XAMEN DE} \large{A}\small{NÁLISIS} \large{M}\small{ATEMÁTICO} \large{III} \\
        \large{30/6/2022}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
%\qquad \qquad \quad \qquad
\hspace{3.5cm}% <<< (3) alternative way to move the numerical table
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|}
        \hline 
        \,\,1& \,\,2 &\,\,3 &\,\,4 & \,\% \\
        \hline
        & & & & \\
        & & & & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\\\\\\
\large \textbf{Apellido y Nombre:}
\vspace{2pt}
\hrule
\end{document}
```